# Tool to Analyze SQL Query

Tags: postgresql

Are there any tools built that can take a postgres query and convert it into a JSON object. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO schema_a.table_a
SELECT * from schema_b.table_b
```

Outputs:

```
{
'type': 'query',
'method': 'INSERT INTO',
'output':
    {
    'type': 'table',
    'schema': 'schema_a'
    'table': 'table_a'
    },
'input':
    {
    'type': 'query',
    'method': 'SELECT',
    'inputs':
    [
        {
        'type': 'table'
        'schema': 'schema_b'
        'table': 'table_b'
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

Doesn't have to be this exactly, but the idea would be something where we could categorize the inputs, outputs, methods and would be flexible enough to be able to handle joins, sub queries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not quite what you're looking for but [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) does support JSON as an output type, which will break down the query into its component parts using PostgreSQL's query parser/planner (some key/values omitted for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT NOT NULL );

EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Test');
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "ModifyTable",
      "Operation": "Insert",
      "Relation Name": "test",
      "Alias": "test"
    }
  }
]

EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) SELECT * FROM test;
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Relation Name": "test",
      "Alias": "test"
    }
  }
]
```

This will certainly be able to tell you every relation used in a query (including complex joins, views, etc). If you use ANALYZE it will be able to tell you the number of output rows (but not contents). This won't be able to tell you inputs to a query.

Comment: The JSON output can be passed on to http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new for a graphical visualization

Comment: That looks good, except my version of postgres is 8.2, and this appears to only be possible in 9.0+ :/

Comment: Yep, that would certainly limit your possibilities. [PostgreSQL 8.2 went end-of-life in 2011](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), might be worth looking at updating. If not, your best bet is probably trying to write a text parser for the EXPLAIN output which is doable but difficult.

Comment: Yeah, upgrading would be great, but not my call sadly. I was hoping someone had built a tool for this already, seems like a project that could take weeks and still be imperfect.